# Ansible - How to combine two separate lists into a list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible

I have two separate lists. The first one is a list of network interfaces gathered by Ansible:

```
"ansible_interfaces": [
        "ens32",
        "ens34"
    ],
```

The second one is a list of IP addresses that I define manually in the inventory:

```
host_ipv4_list:
  - "192.168.0.1"
  - "192.168.1.1"
```

My aim is to combine those two lists in order to get a dictionary with keys and values, that look like this:

```
host_network_info:
  - { "interface": "ens32", "ip": "192.168.0.1" }
  - { "interface": "ens34", "ip": "192.168.1.1" }
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Zip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combination-filters) the two lists and use the resulting list elements to [create dictionaries](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#dict). Combine the dictionaries in a loop:

```
set_fact:
  host_network_info: "{{ host_network_info | default([]) + [dict(interface=item[0], ip=item[1])] }}"
loop: "{{ ansible_interfaces | zip(host_ipv4_list) | list }}"
```

Answer (score 5):

No loop solution:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    host_network_info: "{{ dict(ansible_interfaces | zip(host_ipv4_list)) | 
                               dict2items(key_name='interface', value_name='ip') }}"
```